# Add shading to R base plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a simple plot:

```
x1<- sort(rnorm(100))
x_max <- x1-0.5
x_min <- x1+0.5

plot(x1,type='l')
points(x_max,type='l',col="red")
points(x_min,type='l',col="red")
```

I would like to add grey shading between the two red lines.

I am looking for a solution that uses the basic R plotting function of R and not ggplot.

Comment: Try tweaking  `polygon(c(1:100,100:1), c(x_min, rev(x_max)), col="#eeeeeeaa")`

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly. Feel free to add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `polygon`. If you set the color for the polygon with an alpha channel then things don't overwrite anything. Also adding the suggestion by @rawr to use `panel.first`.

```
x1 <- sort(rnorm(100))
x_max <- x1-0.5
x_min <- x1+0.5

plot(x1, type = 'l', panel.first = polygon(c(1:length(x1),length(x1):1), c(x_min, rev(x_max)), col="#eeeeeeaa", border = NA))
points(x_max,type='l',col="red")
points(x_min,type='l',col="red")
```